# Popcorn.js not rewinding

Tags: javascript, html5-video, popcornjs

I'm using [Popcorn.js](http://popcornjs.org/api) and its extension [Popcorn Capture](https://github.com/rwldrn/popcorn.capture).

I have the following code:

```
function setVidPoster() {
    var video = Popcorn( '#bzm_video' ), poster;
        video.listen( "canplayall", function() {
        this.capture({at: 1});
        this.currentTime(0);
    });
}
```

I'm trying to capture the image 1 second in as the poster, however the video player actually moves to 1 second and says there.  From the Popcorn capture documentation I'm assuming this isn't meant to happen, but I can't figure out how to move the video to the beginning (currentTime should be working afaik from the documentation)

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you're still pursuing this, but I poked around in popcorn.capture, and pushed some changes to the capture repo, to get a poster captured at a certain time, and set back to 0. Might want to give it a try.

My final implementation looked like this:

```
    document.addEventListener( "DOMContentLoaded", function() {

      var p = Popcorn( "#video" );
      p.listen( "canplayall", function() {

        this.capture({ at: 10 });

      });
      p.play().pause();

    }, false );
```

I could not find any problems in Popcorn rewinding, though. If you're still having problems, post a complete working case, and I'll take a look at it :)

Comment: I tried that with the most current version of popcorn.capture and the whole video was disabled. For now due to priorities, I've just gone back to capturing the first frame and staying there with the older version of the plugin, but I will post some actual code when I get a chance

Comment: @Damon, sorry to push you for the code... :) but have you managed something, Im quite stuck where you were 3 years ago.